# custom tkinter progress bar not working for "indeterminate" mode

Tags: python, tkinter, progress-bar, customtkinter, yt-dlp

I'm trying to create a YouTube video downloader GUI using `yt-dlp` and `custom-tkinter` library.

I successfully implemented progressbar using `CTkProgressBar()` inside a `CtkFrame` for "determinate" mode which will show progress of the filesize downloaded.

For videos that doesn't have the filesize, I tried to show "interminate" progressbar but it seems to be not working as expected.

```
app = ctk.CTk()
app.title("App")
app.geometry("300x200")

class ProgressFrame(ctk.CTkFrame):
    def __init__(self, parent: tk.Tk, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(parent, *args, **kwargs)
        self.progressbar = ctk.CTkProgressBar(
                        app, 
                        mode="indeterminate", 
                        indeterminate_speed=5
                    )
        self.progressbar.pack(side="top", expand=False, padx=20, pady=5)

    def update_indeterminate_progressbar(self):
        self.progressbar.step()
        self.progressbar.update()    # Now the progressbar is working properly.

progress_frame = ProgressFrame(app)
# progressbar.set(0)            # for "determinate" progressbar

ytdlp_options = {
            'progress_hooks': [progress_frame.update_indeterminate_progressbar],
            'outtmpl': "path/to/output/file",
            'format': "format id",
        }
video_info = {
    # youtbe video details.
}

with yt_dlp.YoutubeDL(ytdlp_options) as ytdl:
    ytdl.process_ie_result(video_info, download=True)

# progressbar.set(1)            # for "determinate" progressbar

app.mainloop()
```

When I run the above code, The progress bar stays still and there is no any change in progressbar. If I uncomment `progressbar.start()` the progress bar starts moving after the video is downloaded and not during the download.

When I tried to remove the *progress_hook*, `update_indeterminate_progress` and run, I get the same above result.

**EDIT:**

The problems seems to be with my `progress_frame`. its working now after I updated the `progressbar` inside the `update_indeterminate_progress` method.

TIA

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the customtkinter progress bar does its own animation in the same thread that it is created. If you're running some long running code in the same thread, it won't be able to update its appearance.

You'll likely need to download the video in a separate thread or process.,

Comment: The problems seems to be with my progress_frame. its working now after I updated the progressbar inside the `update_indeterminate_progress` method.